# Video stays inline on mobile

Tags: html, css

i have set up a gallery on my website which displays a large embedded video with 3 thumbnail embedded videos underneath which looks great on the desktop but as i switch to the phone view the 3 thumbnail videos stay in line and dont drop underneath each other as i imagined. Meaning you have to scroll away from the phone screen to view. could someone please advise as to what i need to do? below is the html and css code.

```css
    .vid-container {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 52%;
 padding-top: 30px; 
 height: 0; 
}

.vid-container iframe,
.vid-container object,
.vid-container embed {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.vid-list-container {
 width: 92%;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left:4%;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.vid-list {
 width: 1344px;
 position: relative;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
}
.vid-item {
 display: block;
    position: relative;
 width: 18%;
 height: 18%;
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px;
}

.thumb {
 overflow:hidden;
 height: 84%;
}

.thumb img {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 top: -13px;
}

.vid-item .desc {
 color: #21A1D2;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
      <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="m-3 col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-lg-8">
         <h3>This week we are watching....</h3>
           <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
 <iframe id="vid_frame" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RfuNhK_o9no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
           </div>
         
           <div class ="vid-list">
<div class="vid-item" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/HBmDFJRwzQ8'">
 <div class="thumb">
  <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/HBmDFJRwzQ8/0.jpg" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div class="desc">
  Living a healthy lifestyle doesn’t always come easy! But with this one pot meal it doesnt get much easier
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vid-item" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/U0jggZfufGU'">
 <div class="thumb">
  <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/U0jggZfufGU/0.jpg" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div class="desc">
  Hey everyone welcome back! Today I have some easy and delicious summer treats! These are easy and inexpensive treats and taste amazing! I hope you enjoyed!
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vid-item" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/p4b2rFW8cms'">
 <div class="thumb">
  <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/p4b2rFW8cms/0.jpg" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div class="desc">
  From the archives: Once again Gennaro invites us into his home to show us another wholesome home cooked meal.
    </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
       </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that if you added view port meta `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=0.5, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />`
 
like above, also your media query does not respond without viewport for responsive

Comment: thank you for this reply but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: try ` @media (max-width:768px) { .vid-item {width:100%;}  }`

Answer (score 0):

Guess you want to achieve this?
If you are already using bootstrap why not use another nested row for the videos below the 'main'-video?

I replaced the `.vid-list` class with a `.row` bootstrap class and assumed that you want to have three other videos below the main video. Since bootstrap is using 12 columns i divided 12 by 3 and got 4. So i used `.col-md-4` to use 4 columns for one video. On small devices you want to use the full length so you are using `.col-sm-12`. 
And try to avoid using negative top and margin values. I also cleared up some (not everything) of unnecessary code.

```css
.vid-container {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 52%;
 padding-top: 30px; 
 height: 0; 
}

.vid-container iframe,
.vid-container object,
.vid-container embed {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.vid-list-container {
 width: 92%;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left:4%;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.vid-list {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.thumb {
 overflow:hidden;
 height: 84%;
}

.thumb img {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 top: -13px;
}

.vid-item .desc {
 color: #21A1D2;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="m-3 col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-lg-8">
         <h3>This week we are watching....</h3>
         <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe id="vid_frame" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RfuNhK_o9no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
         </div>
         <div class ="row vid-list">
            <div class="vid-item col-sm-12 col-md-4" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/HBmDFJRwzQ8'">
               <div class="thumb">
                  <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/HBmDFJRwzQ8/0.jpg" alt="" />
               </div>
               <div class="desc">
                  Living a healthy lifestyle doesn’t always come easy! But with this one pot meal it doesnt get much easier
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="vid-item col-sm-12 col-md-4" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/U0jggZfufGU'">
               <div class="thumb">
                  <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/U0jggZfufGU/0.jpg" alt="" />
               </div>
               <div class="desc">
                  Hey everyone welcome back! Today I have some easy and delicious summer treats! These are easy and inexpensive treats and taste amazing! I hope you enjoyed!
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="vid-item col-sm-12 col-md-4" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/p4b2rFW8cms'">
               <div class="thumb">
                  <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/p4b2rFW8cms/0.jpg" alt="" />
               </div>
               <div class="desc">
                  From the archives: Once again Gennaro invites us into his home to show us another wholesome home cooked meal.
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```